# SharePoint 2007: Colour coding list cells

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer, list

I have a custom list that is comprised mostly of chice columns.  All columns have the same options.

I've been asked if it's possible to colour the rendered list depending on what choice is made within these columns.  Each choice entry will have a specific colour associated with it.

I'm not so fussed by this being made to happen on the datasheet view but more the rendered html.

I have JQuery as part of my environment.  It's loaded as part of my branding

Any tips / pointers appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick and easy way to do this.  Just paste the code into a .js file and upload into one a Library, add a Content Editor Web Part below the List View, then reference the .js file above.

```
<script src="/path/to/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("td").filter(function() { 
     return $(this).text() == 'Value to Match'; 
})
.css("color", "red");
</script>
```

Link to [jQuery download](http://jquery.com/download/).

Comment: Craig, good tip.  I'll give this a shot and will advise / mark up your answer as I go.

Comment: Hi Craig,  I gave this a go and the colour of the text in the cell changed.  Is it possible to amend this so that the cell changes instead?  I'll be playing with the IE browwer dev tools in the interim and will post back if I solve.

Comment: Definitely doable, since we're just manipulating the DOM and/or CSS. in the 2nd to last line where we're using .css object change to this: .css("background-color","red");

Comment: Yup, got that working after I posted.  +1 and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I was working on a project that used a sharepoint list with a column called "Urgency" that was a choice column with values "Low", "Medium", "High". The client wanted to show the co0lumn in the list view but instead of the text, show a corresponding color - Green for Low, Orange for medium and Red for High. Also I needed to have this configured without downtime or custom code.

I found a great post online here that helped me do exactly that using a calculated column and a content editor webpart, out of the box!

Steps:

Create a column in the list called "Urgency Level" for example. Its a choice column with values "(1) Low", "(2) Medium", "(3) High"

Create s column in the list called "Urgency" which will display the color. This is a calculated column. The formula for this column is

```
  ="<DIV style=’font-weight:bold; font-size:24px; color:”&CHOOSE(RIGHT(LEFT(Urgency Level,2),1),”red”,”orange”,”green”)&”;’>&bull;</DIV>"
```

Add a content editor web part to the bottom of the page and copy the below script into it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var theTDs = document.getElementsByTagName("TD");
var i=0;
var TDContent = " ";
while (i < theTDs.length)
{
try
{
TDContent = theTDs[i].innerText || theTDs[i].textContent;
if ((TDContent.indexOf("<DIV") == 0) && (TDContent.indexOf("</DIV>") >= 0)) {
theTDs[i].innerHTML = TDContent;
}
}
catch(err){}
i=i+1;
}
//
// ExpGroupRenderData overwrites the default SharePoint function
// This part is needed for collapsed groupings
//
function ExpGroupRenderData(htmlToRender, groupName, isLoaded)
{
var tbody=document.getElementById("tbod"+groupName+"_");
var wrapDiv=document.createElement("DIV");
wrapDiv.innerHTML="<TABLE><TBODY id=\"tbod"+ groupName+"_\" isLoaded=\""+isLoaded+ "\">"+htmlToRender+"</TBODY></TABLE>";
var theTBODYTDs = wrapDiv.getElementsByTagName("TD");
var j=0;
var TDContent = " ";
while (j < theTBODYTDs.length)
{
try
{
TDContent = theTBODYTDs[j].innerText || theTBODYTDs[j].textContent;
if ((TDContent.indexOf("<DIV") == 0) && (TDContent.indexOf("</DIV>") >= 0)) {
theTBODYTDs[j].innerHTML = TDContent;
}
}
catch(err){}
j=j+1;
}
tbody.parentNode.replaceChild(wrapDiv.firstChild.firstChild,tbody);
}
</script>
```

Comment: http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/09/01/using-calculated-columns-to-write-html/

Comment: I was hoping something was doable with calculated columns.  The pathtosharepoint column is know.  Nice tips.  I'll try this out.